# Taxonomy hierarchy in filter block of views isotope?

Tags: 7, blocks, views

How can I set the filter block to show a hierarchical taxonomy? As far as I can see there is only a flat list being built by default. How can I change this and apply the hierarchy of a taxonomy?

This is the link of the module, of course do not answer if you do not know what is [views isotope](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_isotope) Module.

Answer (score -1):

First, I'm confused about what you mean by views isotope?

But if you're asking to build a hierarchical taxonomy in view select, there's [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module.

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies hierarchy.

Comment: haven't any of you used views isotope? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_isotope

Comment: Oh that's a cool module, but haven't used it yet since it's still in development mode. No proper release yet.

Answer (score -2):

Try the [Views Term Hierarchy Weight Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_term_hierarchy_weight_field) module

> This module allows you to display, filter or sort terms according to their hierarchical order or hierarchical depth.